# Build UWP TabView in C# (Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls;)

Tags: c#, uwp

I'm interested in dynamically building a UWP TabView control in code. I have not been able to find any documentation demonstrating this after extensive searching.

I'm interested in building a tabview with several tabs and putting controls in the tabs. Any C# example would help as all I've seen so far are preconfigured XAML.

Thus far I'm stuck embarrisingly at TabView tab = new TabView();

Comment: i guess the next step is to attach it to visual tree right?
just Do this SomeGridIntheUi.Children.Add(yourtabview)

Answer (score 2):

Here's a super simple (code behind) example that should get you started.

Consider this basic view with a named frame tag:

```
<Page ...>    
    <Grid>
        <Frame Name="MainPageFrame"/>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

Create your TabItem objects and set their content to whatever you like, in this example, just simple text boxes. Add them to a collection (in this case a List<>) and assign it to the ItemSource property of your TabView. Finally, set the Content property of your frame to your newly crated TabView. That's it!

```
using Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;

namespace UWPTest
{
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
            var tabView = new TabView();
            var itemSource = new List<TabViewItem>
            {
                new TabViewItem{ Header = "Tab 1", Content = new TextBlock{ Text = "Hello Tab 1!"} },
                new TabViewItem{ Header = "Tab 2", Content = new TextBlock{ Text = "Hello Tab 2!"} },
                new TabViewItem{ Header = "Tab 3", Content = new TextBlock{ Text = "Hello Tab 3!"} },
            };
            tabView.TabItemsSource = itemSource;
            MainPageFrame.Content = tabView;
        }
    }
}
```

Hope it helps you.

Comment: @Bizhan I couldn't figure out how to get that code block to render properly. I googled it and now I've become an expert at it 